# How to convert to lowercase a specific pattern in multiple java classes using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, eclipse, expression, lowercase

I am looking to find a way to convert a specific pattern to lower case for an entire Java project (target: *.jrxml).

Basically, I would like to find all expressions matching the following pattern:
$F{TEXT_EXPRESSION}

and then send the TEXT_EXPRESSION string to lower case, so the result would be $F{text_expression}.

I am using Eclipse and I would like to specify a regular expression in the Search and Replace dialog.

Any advice regarding my requirement?

Thank you very much

Charles

Comment: I haven't found any way to do it directly using the find and replace functionality in Eclipse. I coded a custom Java class that does the trick using the File class

Answer (score 0):

I would use perl or sed.  With perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\$F{(.*?)}/\$F{lc($1)}/e' `find [eclipse project folder] -name \*.jrxml`
```